# Why does my app stop showing the progressdialog?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, progressdialog, android-glide

i have created app for receiving image from server with volley and show in recyclerview in my app with glide, my app have progressdialog and show progress when app download image from server with glide but often my app stop in progress and don't work like screenshot below

[image: image description]

i have to close app and open it again what solution for this problem yo can see my code this below

```
 RecyclerView recycler_view;
 static final String url="";
 ArrayList<Image> images;
 GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
 ProgressDialog pd;
 public static Button btn_buy;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

recycler_view=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
btn_buy=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);


pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setCancelable(false);

images=new ArrayList<>();
mAdapter=new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(),images);


RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager=new 
GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

recycler_view.setAdapter(mAdapter);

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
1);

recycler_view.addOnItemTouchListener(new 
GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(),recycler_view, 
new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("images",images);
bundle.putInt("position",position);



FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment=SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
newFragment.show(ft,"slideshow");


}

@Override
public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

}
}));

btn_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,IABactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
});


fetchImages();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                     String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
case 1: {

// If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
if (grantResults.length > 0
&& grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      // permission was granted, yay! Do the
      // contacts-related task you need to do.
    } else {

      // permission denied, boo! Disable the
      // functionality that depends on this permission.
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "دسترسی به حافظه داخلی لغو شد!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return;
  }

  // other 'case' lines to check for other
  // permissions this app might request
}
}



public void fetchImages()
{

pd.setMessage("Please wait ...");
pd.show();


StringRequest req = new StringRequest(url,
  new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      Log.d("", response.toString());
      pd.hide();

      images.clear();
      try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray dataArray = object.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject dataObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

          Image image = new Image();
          image.setName(dataObject.getString("name_client"));

          // JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
          image.setSmall(dataObject.getString("small"));
          image.setOriginal(dataObject.getString("orginal"));
          image.setTimestamp(dataObject.getString("timestamp"));

          images.add(image);

        }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    pd.hide();
  }
});


AppController.getmInstance().addToRequsetQueue(req);

}
}
```

Comment: please attach your logs also

Comment: What are the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.dismiss()` instead of `pd.hide()`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `pd.hide()` use `pd.dismiss()`